# MS SQL Stored Procedure run time error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to rectify error in sp while concatenating the MSSQL queries?

```
SET  @Ws_Sql = 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@WS_STATUS) AS [Status],A.RECNUB AS [Rec #], A.REVCOD AS [Revenue CODE], ' 
IF @LNKOPT = 1 
BEGIN
    SET  @Ws_Sql = @WS_SQL +''' AS [Status],'
END
ELSE IF @LNKOPT = 2
BEGIN
    SET  @Ws_Sql = @WS_SQL +'' + 'Modified' + ' AS [Status],'
END
ELSE IF @LNKOPT = 3
BEGIN
    SET  @Ws_Sql = @WS_SQL +'' + 'Deleted' + ' AS [Status],'
END
ELSE IF @LNKOPT = 4
BEGIN
    SET  @Ws_Sql = @WS_SQL +'' + 'Reprint' + ' AS [Status],'
END
```

Comment: The above stored procedure, status would be added newly which is not in table.based on lnkopt(passsing parameter) which have to come.

Comment: 1) You shouldn't ever have to directly comment on your own questions or answers. If you have more to add, please use the edit link at the bottom of your question, and 2) You do have more to add because you've not told us **what** error message you're getting.

Comment: and 3) If you're getting an error message from constructing a string and then running the SQL, try `PRINT`ing the SQL out before/instead of running it. Even if you can't see the problem yourself then, please add that constructed SQL to your question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to assign an empty value to the [Status] output column, in case @LNKOPT = 1?

In that case, you need to use double apostrophes, to escape the apostrophe character:

```
IF @LNKOPT = 1 
BEGIN
    SET  @Ws_Sql = @WS_SQL +''''' AS [Status],'
END
```

which will result in @Ws_Sql containing: `'' AS [Status]` (otherwise it would result in `' AS [Status]` which will give an error when the @Ws_Sql string is executed).

Comment: Thanks dude this answer was helpful for me.